# Jquery $.get() method taking url from root.Why

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function, directory

I have one root folder www having one folder named myweb in which two pages raw.php and ripe.php exists.
Now my raw.php script code

```
<script>
 $.get("ripe.php", function(result){
 $("body").append(result);
  });
</script>
```

is not working .The working code is

```
<script>
 $.get("myweb/ripe.php", function(result){
 $("body").append(result);
  });
</script>
```

Now I want to know why it is taking url from root folder in jquery.and how can i make it to take url with respect to current folder

Comment: Where is the file making those ajax calls ? Both are relative to the current page.

Comment: @Joseph Do you mean by first block code

Comment: Can you not reference from the document root of the webserver so that it doesn't matter where the calling files are? Something like `$.get('/myweb/ripe.php') ... `

Comment: I don't want to write full address in my all pages

Comment: It is always taking url from root no matter in which js exists:-)

Comment: Is here any other alternative which will work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making ajax requests, the current folder (notated as ./ or the lack thereof) is the location of the html file that was called. If your html file is in the root, then all ajax requests will be relative to the root.

.htaccess files can also affect file paths.

Example: Lets say the www folder is your root and you have this structure:

```
www/
--->index.php
--->myweb/
--->----->script.js
```

When you are on index.php, all requests being made by script.js are being done relative to index.php, not script.js. Your `myweb/ripe.php` is a relative path, not absolute. That tells me that your index file is outside of the myweb folder.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the file you're executing that JS from is located.

If it's located in `http://www.mydomain.com/myweb/raw.php` then ripe.php has to be there too.

Comment: Maybe you can give us the actual links to those files (in case they don't contain sensitive information).

Comment: They are linkless as they are in localhost

Comment: There's not much else to be said than: make sure you're using the correct paths. Chrome's JS console (ctrl+shift+J) can log the requests, just right-click in there and enable XmlHttpRequest logging in the dropdown to see what $.get actually requests. Firebug probably has a similar option.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, that's why I said "probably" in context of Firebug. Though you might want to take a look at [Firebug Tutorial - Logging, Profiling and Command-Line (Part II)](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/10/firebug-tutorial-logging-profiling-and-commandline-part-ii)

Comment: We (atleast I) can't help you without links to the actual files. All I can say is: Take a look at the complete URL in the XmlHttpRequest and make sure that your files are where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your AJAX script in `http://localhost/index.php` then this would be the correct outcome, however if the AJAX script is located in `http://localhost/myweb/index.php` the ajax call should be relative.

Comment: It actually **is** relative in the OP.